# Is there a more efficient way to create my DataTable in C#?

Tags: c#

I have a simple CreateDataTable method in my project, which seems a little clunky and inefficient to me. It works, but is there a tidier way to write this?

```
private static DataTable CreateDataTable()
{

    var table = new DataTable("FileUploads");

    var id = new DataColumn
    {
        DataType = Type.GetType("System.Int32"),
        ColumnName = "Id",
        AutoIncrement = true,
        Unique = true
    };
    table.Columns.Add(id);

    var name = new DataColumn
    {
        DataType = Type.GetType("System.String"),
        ColumnName = "FileName",
        AutoIncrement = false,
        Caption = "FileName",
        ReadOnly = false,
        Unique = false
    };
    table.Columns.Add(name);

    var path = new DataColumn
    {
        DataType = Type.GetType("System.String"),
        ColumnName = "FilePath",
        AutoIncrement = false,
        Caption = "FilePath",
        ReadOnly = false,
        Unique = false
    };

//several more column inserts...

    var primaryKeyColumns = new DataColumn[1];
    primaryKeyColumns[0] = table.Columns["Id"];
    table.PrimaryKey = primaryKeyColumns;

    return table;

}
```

Comment: Can you use typed data tables? You can use the built-in designer, which auto-generates the code you're writing manually. And then you just do `new FileUploadsDataTable`. Mind, `DataTable`s are rather outdated and haven't been updated in quite a while.

Comment: After creating, are you populating this `DataTable` from a database by chance? Something via a `SqlCommand` object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several things you can do...

You can ignore values that you're setting to the default and use constructor params for Column name and type to reduce code use. I would also use `typeof(string)` instead of `Type.GetType("System.String")` to provide compile time errors instead of runtime errors.

Use `AddRange` when adding columns and create them inline.

Get rid of the verbose primary key stuff and use a simple array assignment

This will get you much less code and therefore, less that can go wrong.

```
private static DataTable CreateDataTable()
{
    var table = new DataTable("FileUploads");

    table.Columns.AddRange(new[]{
        new DataColumn("Id", typeof(int))
        {
            AutoIncrement = true,
            Unique = true
        },
        new DataColumn("FileName", typeof(string)),
        new DataColumn("FilePath", typeof(string)),
        // more columns here
    });

    table.PrimaryKey = new []{ table.Columns["id"] };

    return table;
}
```

I got rid of `Caption` too as it defaults to the column name if not set ;)

This is much less verbose and should be easier to read too.